# Is there a way to give access to FB public app for a few dedicated FB users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to specify only a small number of FB user profiles that can login with my FB Web app? With a possibility to manage the list making FB API calls (add a user to a list or remove it).

A preferred algorithm is as follows.

1. A user gives me a link (or id) to her FB profile (https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=[ID] or https://www.facebook.com/john_doe)
2. I make a FB API call and save this account eligible to login with my app.
3. A user then logs in with my app on the app's web page with FB login button. And my app accepts the login since the user is allowed to login.

I would like to avoid setting up a local DB and store allowed user ids with it. Because since `v2.0` FB made it impossible to match real user id with app scoped user id.
I mean:

1. A user gives me her real user id.
2. I store it in my local DB.
3. Then the users logs in with my app, but both `FB.login` and `FB.api(/me)` return app scoped user id, not a real user id. And it is not the one that is stored in my local DB. And there are no means to map it with a real one. So I won't be able to distinguish a user.

Is there some best practice to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

- Let everyone use the login button
- by default, users do not have access but can "request" it
- you build a backend, where you list all user requests
- in the backend, you can approve/deny users
- after that, users can go further in your app

Your solutions will not work, because you cannot get access to the username (john_doe) or the "real" id with the API.

Comment: Did exactly the same) Thank you.